# Android Pie: WebView showing error for plain HTTP on some sites, even with usesClearTextTraffic="true"

Tags: android, http, webview

We have a WebView in our android app that end users can browse to whatever site they want. Android Pie disabled plain HTTP by default, so we added usesClearTextTraffic="true" to our manifest.

This works for some sites, but not for others, like google.com! On the sites that don't work, we still get net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED as if we hadn't set the manifest setting.

[image: Screenshot of webview HTTP error]

I thought it might be related to HSTS, but in that case I would just expect the WebView to redirect to HTTPS immediately.

So the question is, why is Android WebView still unable to browse some sites by plain HTTP, even when usesClearTextTraffic is turned on in manifest?

(PS We do not have a network security config)

We are testing on Google Pixel 1XL.

plain http not working:

- http://google.com
- http://umajin.com
- http://targetprocess.com

plain http working:

- http://facebook.com
- http://twitter.com
- http://gmail.com

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.umajin.umajinviewer">

    <permission android:name="com.umajin.umajinviewer.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.umajin.umajinviewer.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application android:label="Umajin Preview"
                 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity android:name="Umajin"
                  android:label="Umajin Preview"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
                  android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
                  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                  android:largeHeap="true"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask"
                  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter
                android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.umajin.umajinviewer" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".MyIntentService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="<redacted>"/>

        <!-- Specify which class to instantiate for the alarm messages -->
        <receiver android:name="com.umajin.app.AlarmReceiver" >
        </receiver>

        <!-- Use this receiver if you to excute something at boot -->
        <!-- Required if you want alarms to survive a device restart -->
        <receiver
           android:name="com.umajin.umajinviewer.BootReceiver"
           android:enabled="true"
           android:exported="true"
           android:label="BootReceiver">
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
           </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- end boot receiver -->

        <!-- Add this to play private video files in fullscreen externally through intents. -->
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.umajin.umajinviewer.files"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
        <!-- Android Pie specific fix for crash on Google Maps. Throws a ClassNotFoundException when it fails to
             find "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion".
             See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782806/android-google-maps-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lorg-a -->
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
    </application>

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" /> 
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <!-- WRITE no longer implies READ. By agreement, we always ask 
         for both at a time as the user prompts are identical and it can appear to 
         a user that they have been asked for the same thing twice even though the
         underlying permission asked for may be different. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- FINE and COARSE permissions result in the same prompt being displayed to the
         user. It can appear to the user that they have been asked for the same thing
         twice. By agreement, we always ask for both in one request
         to the user to avoid confusing the user. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <!-- Used for Samsung fingerprint scanner. -->
    <uses-permission android:name= "com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY"/>

    <!-- Required for Bluetooth LE -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <!-- Use this permission if you want your applications to launch on startup -->
    <!-- Required if you want alarms to survive a device restart -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <!-- Required for WIFI scanning -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you please post your Manifest?

Comment: Sure, I have added the Manifest. Thanks

Comment: Please check out the solution

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Solution:**

As I've observed the `Manifest.xml` of yours, you have used the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the `<activity>` tag.

As you can see in the [Documentation of the activity tag](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element), it does not offer any functionality as such in the syntax provided in the docs.

As you can see in the screenshot below, the description of the cleartexttraffic is quite straight forward.

[image: About Clear Text Traffic]

Also, if you look at the [Documentation of the application tag](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element), you will notice that `android:usesCleartextTraffic` is one of the attributes of the `Application Tag`.

So the only fix required here is to remove the attribute in from the **activity** tag and use it in the **application** tag and there is no activity tag support for `android:usesCleartextTraffic`.

> Starting with Android 9 (Pie) Clear Text Traffic is disabled by default.

Hence, the solution would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Try it, Please comment if you have any issues related to this.

Comment: The only mystery is why some sites were apparently working without it. Perhaps they are in HSTS lists and therefore redirect to HTTPS within the webview.

Comment: @O'Rooney Yeah, Anyway I'm glad the answer helped. :)

Comment: I followed all those steps , and my webview still black in those devices . any other idea

Comment: can you take a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634016/android-9-api-28-only-webview-is-showing-a-black-pop-up-in-some-devices?noredirect=1#comment99894473_56634016