# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

Tags: android, cordova, http, ionic4

I have gone through this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752716/why-am-i-seeing-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-errors-after-upgrading-to-cordo), and I have made subsequent changes but still can't solve the problem. Still giving me the same error.
Can someone please help me out. Thanks in advance
Here is my piece of code from config.xml

```
 <widget id="com.farm.fork" version="0.0.1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">


<platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" >
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
```

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

AndoidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.farm.fork" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService" />
        <service android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.OnNotificationOpenReceiver" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/accent" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_performance_collection_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="true" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your final Androidmanifest.xml file

Comment: Uploaded androidmanifest.ml file

Comment: Can you try this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config> in your network_security_config.xml

Comment: now I am getting this error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: try adding <access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" /> in config.xml

Comment: It didn't solve the solver. Getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Comment: In which android os version you are trying to use

Comment: Android version is 9

Comment: what is the ionic-weview version ?

Comment: The ionic-webview-version is 5.17.1

Answer (score 19):

After a few days of struggle, this works for me, and I hope this also works for you.
add this to your CONFIG.XML, top of your code.

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

and this, under the platform android.

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" 
   mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
     <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
 </edit-config>
 <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" 
 target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
```

add the follow code to this file "resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">YOUR DOMAIN HERE/IP</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was losing my mind on this problem in the last 4 days.

Comment: You are the subject.

Answer (score 16):

Open AndroidManifest.xml and add the following line to `<application>` tag:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Refer the image below:

[image]

Comment: thanks. adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" t my aplication works fine for me.

Comment: localhost is not working yet

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your network_security_config.xml

from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

notice the change in the tag ***domain-config*** to ***base-config***

Comment: Okay I will try

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Swayangjit I added base config tag in network_security_config.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>

  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
  </base-config>

    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.43.147:3000</domain> <!--Ip address-->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.43.147:3000/products</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2 </domain>

    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

After that, I was getting connection refused error because I was trying to connect to localhost by mobile which is not possible. Instead, you have to use your IP address.
For ex: http://localhost:3000 won't work on the android device instead you have to use the IP address of local network like this

http://IP-addrees:3000.
Note: You can find IP address through ipconfig command

Comment: If you are running both server and emulator on your computer, `127.0.0.1` will refer to the emulator itself and not the server. The advantage of using `10.0.2.2` is that you don't care about the real IP so it is easier to share the project while it also works when your machine is not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
This work for me!!
```

*path: ..\resources\android\xml\network_security_config.xml*

```
**<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">Ip address</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>**
```