# TypeError: Failed to fetch - Only on Cordova application

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, cordova, svelte

I have an express server which has an API endpoint of /todo/set which gets a JSON, POST request.
This API uses cors.

Additionally, I have a Cordova android application (which built with Svelte) and I'm trying to make a request via fetch to the express server. This is what the request looks like:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:8080/todo/set`, {
    method: "post",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'Text': 'Test!'
    }),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
})
```

This isn't working, the server is not getting the request. So I've tried to debug it a little and did this:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:8080/todo/set`, {
    method: "post",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'Text': 'Test!'
    }),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
}).then(res => alert(res)).catch(err => alert(err))
```

After running it I've got "TypeError: Failed to fetch" on the alert. So I've tried it once again, This time checked it outside of the Cordova (Only Svelte on a website). This time it's all worked and I got status 200 from the server.

- It's also tested with Postman and it's working as expected

So I understood that the issue is related to Cordova, But I can't find why it happends. Does someone know how I can solve it?

**An update:** Tried to add a browser platform to Cordova and tried there. It's working on the browser.

Comment: are you testing the cordova application on your mobile device ?

Comment: @OmG3r Tried it both on emulator and on my device. Got the same result :/

Comment: try replacing 'localhost' with your local IP address 192.168.1.x (you need to replace x), you can find it using 'ipconfig' for windows, and 'ifconfig' for linux

Comment: Maybe add for what version and platform, that would help

Comment: @OmG3r Tried it, Still not working. I've even tried it on an external device and same.

Comment: @Eric I'm using cordova 10.0.0. Developing it on Arch Linux, Kernel 5.9.14-arch1-1. The application is for Android (My phone is Samsung Note 9, But it's not working on my emulator too).

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution. If someone comes here after non-stop google search, here it is:
[Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116787/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted)

Comment: Adding the permissions and application note did work for me as well. I had internet permission already.