# Android 9 API 28 ONLY WebView is showing a black pop up in some devices

Tags: android, http, xamarin.forms, webview, android-9.0-pie

I have been trying to figure out why one of the pop-ups inside a webview is showing a black screen in some devices. please see attach
The URL works as URI but not inside the webview.

note: it seems the url have javascript issues. not sure why android 9 block its content

[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080", source: https://mylink.com/js/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js (3)

Edit: I use a render to being able to get current location

xaml :

```
 <local:GeoWebView x:Name="Webview" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

c#

```
Webview.Source = new UrlWebViewSource
            {
               Url=https://MyLink.com/thisismytesturl.htm
            };
```

Render Android :

```
public class GeoWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public GeoWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

          protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
         {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled=true;
          Control.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically=true;
            Control.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebClient());
        }
    }

    public class MyWebClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        public override void OnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(string 
         origin, GeolocationPermissions.ICallback callback)
        {
            callback.Invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    }
```

2.it suppose to show something similar to the image.[image]

Comment: What is supposed to show

Comment: How is the page loaded? Local source HTML, URL, URL but with edited code?

Comment: 1. How you updated any of the WebClient code or are you using the standard client? 2. Have you edited any of the properties of the webview? 3. When you use the default browser of that device, do you see the black screen?

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint in: protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
{} and check to see if that function is hit when you click on the popup? Does it recreate a new webclient everytime?

Comment: Also what changes to the code were made before it stopped working? Or was the popup not working since before you touched it?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I edited the question. Just to note that this happens only with API 28. TheWebview loads just fine. when you try to open another link inside the view. the black pop up appears.

Comment: @Pxaml I use your codes and set the url to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/), I click the link in the webView and didn't see the black pop up. Is the problem with the web url? Any more steps I need to do to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks for try! if I click the link alone as URI it worked but not when is in the webview. the url has issues with javascript that's all I know . Please see a new edit.

Comment: Can you give me a `Url` sample  that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Thanks, @JackHua-MSFT! I am not able to share the link.I know it makes it harder.

Comment: Ok, I will try it on my side later.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps mentioned below:

1. Editing useCleartextTraffic attribute in manifest file.
2. Adding Network Security Config.

   ```
   <application
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
   ```

Comment: I use Game maker Studio and cant add this to the application tag directly, but is it ok to have two application tags?

Comment: Nope it should contain a single application tag