# NativeScript Google maps java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin, nativescript-google-maps-sdk

I switched to {N} 5.0, now i have an issue with nativescript-google-map-sdk, 
same error as here:
[Android Google maps java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782806/android-google-maps-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lorg-a)

The issue with Android API 28, there is a config that should be set manually in manifetst, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library

When I add

```
 <uses-library
  android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
  android:required="false" />
```

to my App_Resources/Android/AndroidManifest.xml

i get this error

```
* What went wrong:
```

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Android resource linking failed
>     Output:  /Users/rudm/dev/mobile/new5/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:21: error: unexpected element  found in .

is there a way to make google map working with {N} 5.0?

Answer (score 2):

Just add uses-library at the end of application tag

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
</application>
```