# google maps api app keeps stopping in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to create an application which utilizes Google Maps API. I followed the instructions (installed Google Play Services, created an API key, copied, and then pasted it in .xml file), but when I try to run this app, I get "Maps Demo (the name of the app) keeps stopping" message. (I use Nexus 5 API 28 AVD as an emulator) What might be reasons for that and how to solve this problem?

Logcat:

--------- beginning of crash

```
2018-11-24 09:07:55.191 2653-2803/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
    Process: com.example.user.mapdirectionsample, PID: 2653
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
        at fa.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):3)
        at ez.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):3)
        at fb.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):15)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.al.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):6)
        at ee.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):21)
        at ee.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):8)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000d/MapsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000d/MapsDynamite.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at ac.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):4)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at fa.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):3) 
        at ez.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):3) 
        at fb.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):15) 
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.al.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):6) 
        at ee.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):21) 
        at ee.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14574084@14.5.74 (100700-219897028):8)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: Please post the error logs/stack trace that you see in the Logcat when the crash occurs, will help us help you better.

Comment: This question was asked here and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782806/android-google-maps-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lorg-a