# Admob shows Test ads with test adUnitId but for real adUnitId app crashed

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

When I test my app with test(ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111) adUnitId it shows ads but when I replace test adUnitId with real one app get crashed.

**Error Log:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
Process: biz.coolpage.aashish.app, PID: 13682
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
    at jp.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):3)
    at jo.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):3)
    at jq.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):19)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.aq.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):15)
    at iu.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):19)
    at iu.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):8)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000f/AdsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000f/AdsDynamite.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at ad.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):4)
```

Inside LinearLayout in xml file:

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Inside the OnCreate method:

```
    MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.AdMob_app_id));
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Could be proguard issue.

Comment: @Ranjan But, I used proguard file only in release mode. So in that case also proguard issue happens during testing??

Comment: This looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782806/android-google-maps-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lorg-a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After wasting so many hours finally I got the root cause of this crash.

When you add an app in your AdMob account then **by default ads based on location has ON**. So, if your app doesn't have location permission then the app crashed.

**Solution:--**

Either you will turn OFF ads based on the location from your AdMob account

**OR**

you can ask your users to provide access to their locations.