# Android emulator with phone debugging

Tags: android

I'm using an emulator to open the apk file but it doesn't work knowing i installed all the sdk needed

Comment: You should add your generated Log file ( https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat ) with the error in question, to identify the issue and get a quicker response.

Comment: Please don't delete with original question when you edit. We lose context and have no idea what we need to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50794266/4880379)

adding this inside your AndroidManifest's `<application>` element:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

should do the trick