# Required by:project :react-native-maps Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-compat' that satisfies the version constraints

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-fragments, react-native-maps

I am creating an app using react-native and react-native-map. Below are the versions of packages

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.0",
"react-native-maps": "^0.23.0",
```

I am just following the documentation and I am getting the error specified in subject line,I tried to verify but no luck

```
Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :react-native-maps
   Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-compat' that satisfies the version constraints:
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:loader:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:customview:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:viewpager:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:drawerlayout:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0

Could not resolve com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :react-native-maps
    Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-annotations' that satisfies the version constraints:
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:collections:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:cursoradapter:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:documentfile:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:loader:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:print:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1' --> 'android.arch.core:common:1.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:customview:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:viewpager:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:drawerlayout:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:interpolator:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:loader:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1' --> 'android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0

Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0.
Required by:
    project :react-native-maps
    Cannot find a version of 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' that satisfies the version constraints:
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1'
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0

Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0.
Required by:
    project :react-native-maps
    Cannot find a version of 'android.arch.lifecycle:common' that satisfies the version constraints:
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:loader:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1'
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:common' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0

Could not resolve android.arch.core:common:1.0.0.
Required by:
    project :react-native-maps
    Cannot find a version of 'android.arch.core:common' that satisfies the version constraints:
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1' --> 'android.arch.core:common:1.1.1'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:loader:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1' --> 'android.arch.core:common:1.1.1'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:loader:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1' --> 'android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1' --> 'android.arch.core:common:1.1.1'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:loader:28.0.0' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1' --> 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1' --> 'android.arch.core:common:1.1.1'
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'android.arch.core:common' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0

Could not resolve com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :react-native-maps
    Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-core-utils' that satisfies the version constraints:
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0

Could not resolve com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :react-native-maps
    Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-core-ui' that satisfies the version constraints:
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0'
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0'
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
      Constraint path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0

Could not resolve com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :react-native-maps
    Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-fragment' that satisfies the version constraints:
      Dependency path 'ReactFlexNativeBaseTaxi:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.0' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a known [issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2737). It is always worth checking the dependency's repo to see if an issue exists.

According to this [answer](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2737#issuecomment-472341877) in the thread

> Next release will fix it!
>
> If you guys prefer to locking to a specific commit you can use the
>   current one:

If you update your `package.json` so that `react-native-maps` looks like this and re-run `npm install` (after deleting your node_modules) it should resolve the issue.

```
"react-native-maps": "https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps.git#c102c36d895cbef8b6a8deefd4c58fb0dc17638e",
```

If it doesn't then you will have to wait for the next release to come out.

---

According to one of the [answers](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2737#issuecomment-472713634) on the thread you may also need to follow the solutions from this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782806/android-google-maps-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lorg-a).

Where you either update `google-play-services` to version `16.1.0` or add

```
<uses-library
      android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
      android:required="false" />
```

inside the `application` tags of your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I am getting this error now C:\Users\skt\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\3.12.1\dc6d02e4e68514eff5631963e28ca7742ac69efe\okhttp-3.12.1.jar: D8: Type `org.conscrypt.Conscrypt` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `java.security.Provider okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform.getProvider()`

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug FAILED
java.io.IOException: Could not create empty folder C:\Users\SKT\dev\Github\react

Comment: As I said, if using the master from the repo doesn’t work you’ll have to wait for the new release or you should post your issue on that thread. You could also create a project using the previous working version of react-native.  Use `react-native init newproject --version react-native@0.58.6` and that should get around the problem, then you can upgrade once the issue is fixed

Comment: After updating googleplayservice to 16.1.0 , error solved but getting error mesage on screen "having trouble with google playservice "

Comment: Initing with previous version of RN (0.58.6 as suggested) doesn't help - build failed with  error: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  C:\a_test\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get through by installing a specific version (i.e. `npm i react-native-maps@0.27.1`). Worked like a charm.

The following is what my root build.gradle looks like.

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "1.3.1"
    }
```